# @PathParam: No value being passed

Tags: rest, kotlin, jax-rs, quarkus, path-parameter

I'm building a REST api using Quarkus and Kotlin. I'm trying to include a path parameter in my function by using the @PathParam annotation. This is what I have:

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{userId}")
    fun getUser(@PathParam userId: UUID) : GetUserResponse =
        try {
            GetUserSuccess(userRepository.find("id", userId))
        } catch (e: NotFoundException) {
            GetUserFailure(e)
        }
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error stating that there's no value being passed for parameter value.

I googled some stuff, and most of what I found is about wrong imports. I double checked that part, but I import the correct one: import javax.ws.rs.*, which also includes the PathParam.

Anyone knows what's wrong with this?

Comment: If you make the `userId` parameter type `String`, does that change? I'm not sure `UUID` is supported by default.

Comment: @PathParam("userId")

Comment: @Ladicek, changing it to String didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion tho!

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, That did something! I've posted an answer which worked, based on your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Ah of course, I have no idea how I could have missed the missing annotation attribute! Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer would be to change it to:

```
fun getUser(@PathParam("userId") userId : UUID)
```

Inspirerd by Paul Samsotha's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could also use the `@RestPath` annotation from RESTEasy:

```kotlin
fun getUser(@RestPath userId: UUID)
```